# Remote webdriver with opera and edge browser

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge, opera, remotewebdriver

Can't connect to opera and edge webdriver through hub. 
My procedure:

- start hub in cmd:

  ```
     java -jar C:\path\to\selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar -role hub
  ```
- start node in cmd:

  ```
          java -Dwebdriver.opera.driver=C:\path\to\operadriver.exe -
          Dwebdriver.edge.driver=C:\path\to\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe -jar 
          C:\path\to\selenium-server-standalone-
          3.7.1.jar -role node -hub http://mylocalhost:4444/grid/register 
          -browser "browserName=opera,maxInstances=5,platform=Windows" -
          browser "browserName=edge,maxInstances=5,platform=Windows"
  ```

And run this test for Opera:

```
               WebDriver driver;
               String nodeURL;
               nodeURL = "http://mylocalhost:5555/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("opera");
        capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), capabilities);
        driver.get("https://www.google.ru/");
```

And for Edge:

```
               WebDriver driver;
               String nodeURL;
               nodeURL = "http://mylocalhost:5555/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("opera");
        capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), capabilities);
        driver.get("https://www.google.ru/");
```

This is cause exception for Opera:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Opera binary
```

And exception for Edge:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
```

I know that this code work fine for Chrome and firefox. Anyone know how to apply this for Opera ana Edge?